# Categorize score as high or low

Tags: design

Im working on a application that uses camera motion detection to determine changes from high to low level of motion and vise versa.

The motion detection algorithm returns a single score value for every frame of the motion at about 10-30fps.

What i need is a way to accuratley determine where these changes changes occur.

- I don't know what range of score the low values will have
- I don't know what range of score the high values will have
- I don't know how big off a difference there will be between high and low values.

How would you handle this problem?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The first part of the question is just an introduction to my real question. Im not asking anything about the motion detection itself. What im asking is a way to categorize a continous stream of values as high or low. What community would be the place to ask a software engeneering problem like this?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a software engineer, the first two things I would do to handle such a problem is

- clarify vague requirements
- gather more information about the system

The requirement which is not precisely described here is what "high" or "low" level of motion actually shall mean. Does this relate to some perceiption of the camera's user, or a specific speed they move the camera? Is there an existing, more strict definition in this domain? Does the one who gave you this task have a specific idea of what these terms shall mean? These are the question I would ask here.

To gather more information about the system, I would

- look what kind of documentation the vendor/author of the motion detection algorithm has provided (or ask them directly, if there are no docs)
- try out the motion sensor of a real camera and log the values into a file to gather some data and see in what range they will typically be.
- if somehow possible, measure how the speed of motion of the camera relates to the returned values of the algorithm (which means you need an independent, reliable way of measuring the speed of the camera movement, some kind of test bench with speed sensors etc.)

This maybe not the answer you are looking for, but on the few pieces of information you gave in the question the best one I can give you. What definitely not works is just looking at the values in the data stream and guess which of them qualify as "high" and which ones as "low". From the pure data in that stream, one cannot derive a useful metrics for measuring "high" and "low".